# Tensorflow lite negative predictions in binary classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I was basically hoping to prepare my model for distribution through pyinstaller. And since packaging tensorflow lead to the final executable file size of about 500mbs. I resorted to making use of tensorflow lite.

Now the issue is that when I convert the model to tflite (quantized or not) it gives the following as output for whichever image I input.

```
array([[-1.3749948e+23]], dtype=float32)
```

The following is my code for model conversion

```
import tensorflow as tf

m = load_model("weights.best.hdf5")
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(m)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
```

And following is the code to test the tflite model

```
import tflite_runtime.interpreter as tflite
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_quant_model)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
inputdets = interpreter.get_input_details()
outputdets = interpreter.get_output_details()

import imageio
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = imageio.imread("1 (162).jpg")/256.0

final = cv2.resize(img,(150,150))
input_data = np.array([final],dtype=np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(inputdets[0]['index'], input_data)
interpreter.get_tensor(outputdets[0]['index'])
```

**Output from the keras model**

array([[0.9934516]], dtype=float32)

**Output from the tflite model**

array([[-1.3749948e+23]], dtype=float32)

**Additional Info**

Model Accuracy when trained on keras

98%

Input details

```
[{'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'index': 0,
  'name': 'input_3',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
   'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
  'shape': array([  1, 150, 150,   3], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([  1, 150, 150,   3], dtype=int32),
  'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

output details

```
[{'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'index': 21,
  'name': 'Identity',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
   'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
  'shape': array([1, 1], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([1, 1], dtype=int32),
  'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `interpreter.invoke()` before you read the results. https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python

Update your code as follows:

```
...
...
interpreter.set_tensor(inputdets[0]['index'], input_data)
interpreter.invoke()
result = interpreter.get_tensor(outputdets[0]['index']) 
..
..
```

Comment: It finally worked. Thank god. Hope you have a wonderful day. :p